# Allow Internet access only 1 IP in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, ip, connection, blocking

I would like to block internet connections to all IP's except 1 in Windows XP.

How can I do it most easily?

Comment: You can do this with the Windows Firewall.  What have you tried?  Of course I have to add be sure ALL UPDATES are installed before you do this.

Comment: Problem is that someone else can then change settings in windows firewall back. XP account has administrator rights which I can't take away.

Comment: If they have Administrator rights which cannot be removed then this problem cannot be solved.  Anything you do can be reversed by anyone with the knowledge to do so.

Comment: Maybe there is some application I can use to change connections rules.Ofcourse access to this applications must be password protected when trying to open it.

Comment: Where is windows firewall I can set rule to block all connections except 1?

Comment: How you configured the Windows Firewall to do that is well documented on this very website.

Comment: Except that the Windows XP firewall only filters incoming connections, not outgoing...

Comment: Exactly and I need to filter outgoing connections